# Bootstrap modal showing inside modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have modal and when an item is clicked inside of that modal next modal will open but the modal is opening inside first modal but i want is modal to be opened from absolute not inside of other

[image]

Its my code

```
<ul><br/><span><b>Uploaded Assignment Document</b></span>
  <li ng-repeat="file in files">
    <document-viewer link="file.file_name" index="$index" actual="file.actual_name"></document-viewer><img src="/images/icons/cross.png" ng-click="deleteAssignmentFile(file)" class="pull-right"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`document-viewer` is an angular directive

Comment: Have you tried doing something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528173/bootstrap-open-another-modal-in-modal)?

Comment: yes but not worked ,, actually its nested modal