# I need create modal within modal using twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is that possible to create modal within modal? If possible please help me to create modal within modal and within one more modal it means i need to create three modal and second modal should contain drop down using twitter bootstrap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap: Open Another Modal in Modal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528173/bootstrap-open-another-modal-in-modal)

Answer (score 2):

According to Bootstrap:

> Multiple open modals not supported Be sure not to open a modal while
>   another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time
>   requires custom code.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals