# Is it possible to make a modal inside a modal? (nested modal)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

On a project, I'd like to have a bootstrap modal inside another one. When you click button1=> a modal open. Then on a button2 which is on this modal, it opens another modal.

Can bootstrap (and I) do it?

Thanks,

Stéphane.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It's not very neat.

Comment: Do you already tried it? I'm in doubt because of your statement "Can bootstrap **(and I)** do it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that.This link might help you.
http://www.bootply.com/qRsvPSrcO5

additional links
http://www.bootply.com/61322
[Bootstrap: Open Another Modal in Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528173/bootstrap-open-another-modal-in-modal)