# Set focus on a input control contained in a second level bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, bootstrap-modal, vuejs2

I'm using Vue.js 2.1.10 and Bootstrap 3.3.7 to show a modal that opens another modal dialog. Each modal dialog is contained in a distinct component. Inside the 1st component, there is a reference to the 2nd component (`select-travler`).

According to the [Bootsrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), I have to set the focus by listening to the event `shown.bs.modal`. This works great to set the focus on an input control contained in the 1st modal. **Problem:** this way doesn't work when the modal is above another modal.

The 1st modal component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div ref="tripEdit" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <!-- Inbeded component -->
        <select-travler ref="selectTravler"></select-travler>
        <!-- /Inbeded component -->

        <div class="modal-lg modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body container form-horizontal">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="travler_name" class="control-label">
                            Travler's name
                        </label>
                        <input id="travler_name" ref="travler_name"
                            v-model="travler_name"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                travler_name: null,
            }
        },

        methods: {
            show (operationType) {
                $(this.$refs.tripEdit).modal('show');

                let that = this;
                $(this.$refs.tripEdit).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                    $(that.$refs.travler_name).focus();
                });

                if (operationType === 'newTravel') {
                    this.$refs.selectTravler.show();
                }
            },            
        },
    }
</script>
```

The 2nd component contains a similar layout with the following `show` method:

```
show () {
    $(this.$refs.selectTravler).modal('show');

    let that = this;
    $(this.$refs.selectTravler).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $(that.$refs.people_names).focus();
    });
},
```

When the 2nd modal opens, the focus is still on the 1st modal behind the 2nd modal dialog (I can see the caret blinking in `travler_name`). How can I set the focus on `people_names` when the 2nd modal is shown?

Comment: It looks to me like you are adding new `shown.bs.modal` handlers every time a modal is shown, and more than that, you're adding them *after* the modal is triggered to be shown. You probably want to move the `.on(...)` code into the mounted event. Also, don't forget to *remove* the handler when the modal is destroyed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are really several issues at play here. First, as I mentioned in the comment above, you are not properly adding and removing the `shown.bs.modal` event handlers.

Second, because your second modal is nested inside the first modal, the `shown.bs.modal` event will bubble up to the parent modal and it's handler will fire. Initially I thought `stopPropagation` would be a good way to handle this, but in the end, I simply de-nested the `submodal` component in the template.

Here is an example of this behavior actually working.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("sub-modal", {
  template: "#submodal",
  methods: {
    show() {
      $(this.$el).modal("show")
    },
    onShown(event) {
      console.log("submodal onshown")
      this.$refs.input.focus()
    }
  },
  mounted() {
   $(this.$el).on("shown.bs.modal", this.onShown)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    $(this.$el).off("shown.bs.modal", this.onShown)
  }
})

Vue.component("modal", {
  template: "#modal",
  methods: {
    show() {
      $(this.$refs.modal).modal("show")
    },
    showSubModal() {
      this.$refs.submodal.show()
    },
    onShown(event) {
      console.log("parent")
      this.$refs.input.focus()
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    $(this.$refs.modal).on("shown.bs.modal", this.onShown)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    $(this.$refs.modal).off("shown.bs.modal", this.onShown)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <modal ref="modal"></modal>
  <button @click="$refs.modal.show()" class="btn">Show Modal</button>
</div>

<template id="submodal">
  <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input ref="input" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->

</template>

<template id="modal">
  <div>
    <div ref="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">

      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Stuff
            <input ref="input" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button @click="showSubModal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show Sub Modal</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
    <sub-modal ref="submodal"></sub-modal>
  </div>
</template>
```

Also, for future readers, I got some useful information about how to construct the template for the modal component used above from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30876481/38065). Specifically, unless you manually specify a z-index for the modal, the modal that appears last in HTML will have a higher z-index. The implication being the `submodal` component needs to come second in the template.

Comment: Great post. Somehow I still didn't make it on my side for the 2nd focus. I implemented your code in mine and added `console.log("parent.")` in the modal `onShown` method and `console.log("submodal.")` in the submodal `onShown` method.
After pressing the 1st button, the councole displays: `parent.`.
After pressing the 2nd button (Show Sub Modal) the councole displays: `parent. submodal. parent. parent.`. Is this normal? I did write `event.stopPropagation();` exactly as you did.

Comment: @Warrio I'm not sure what's going on with your's specifically, but I did notice that when one modal is *nested* inside the other, then `shown.bs.modal` is triggered twice for the parent. I updated the above code to remove the nested submodal, and now the event fires just the once. It also likely removes the need for `stopPropagation`.

Comment: I can't believe it!! it works :D I definitely owe you a beer or two :D If you one day, you visit Belgrade, send a msg!! Awesome :D

Comment: @Warrio Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue. A b-modal forces focus to stay in the modal. You can disable it by adding a *no-enforce-focus* attribute.

> no-enforce-focus **Boolean**  **false**   Disables the enforce focus routine
> which maintains focus inside the modal

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal

Answer (score 0):

This means that the element you're trying to focus is not properly referenced.
Trying to `console.log(element);` the line before focussing people_names. To see if you're getting the right element.

```
show () {
    $(this.$refs.selectTravler).modal('show');

    let element = this.$refs.people_names;
    $(this.$refs.selectTravler).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $(element).focus();
    });
},
```

Have you considered v-show to open and close your modals ?