# Wrong focus after closing a 2nd modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal

I'm using vue.js 2 and bootsrap 3 to open a modal that opens a 2nd modal.

Few days ago, I asked a question on how to set a focus on a control contained in a 2nd modal. I got a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617289/set-focus-on-a-input-control-contained-in-a-second-level-bootstrap-modal/45618269#45618269) that solved the issue.

**Problem**
When opening the 1st modal, the user is able to scroll through it to see its bottom. But after opening and closing the 2nd modal, the focus moves to the page that contains the 1st modal. and when the user scrolls to see the rest of the 1st modal, he scrolls the page behind that 1st modal.

It is very uncomfortable to use especially when the modal is bigger than the screen height. Is there a way to prevent this?

To reproduce this issue, open the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617289/set-focus-on-a-input-control-contained-in-a-second-level-bootstrap-modal/45618269#45618269) and click on "Expand snippet"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a modified version of the previous answer that sets the focus back to the original modal after the sub modal is closed.

The change is here:

```
$(this.$refs.submodal.$el).on("hidden.bs.modal", this.onShown)
```

This is added in the `mounted` handler. It adds a handler to the `hidden.bs.modal` event of the sub modal. It also removes the handler when the component is destroyed.

Additionally, because closing a modal removes the `modal-open` class that is assigned to the body when a modal opens, the code below adds that class to the body whenever `onShown` is called so that the scroll is not affected for the parent modal.

```
$("body").addClass("modal-open")
```

Here is a working example.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("sub-modal", {
  template: "#submodal",
  methods: {
    show() {
      $(this.$el).modal("show")
    },
    onShown(event) {
      console.log("submodal onshown")
      this.$refs.input.focus()
    }
  },
  mounted() {
   $(this.$el).on("shown.bs.modal", this.onShown)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    $(this.$el).off("shown.bs.modal", this.onShown)
  }
})

Vue.component("modal", {
  template: "#modal",
  methods: {
    show() {
      $(this.$refs.modal).modal("show")
    },
    showSubModal() {
      this.$refs.submodal.show()
    },
    onShown(event) {
      console.log("parent")
      this.$refs.input.focus()
      // Add the "modal-open" class back to the body in case
      // it was removed by the sub modal
      $("body").addClass("modal-open")
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    $(this.$refs.modal).on("shown.bs.modal", this.onShown)
    $(this.$refs.submodal.$el).on("hidden.bs.modal", this.onShown)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    $(this.$refs.modal).off("shown.bs.modal", this.onShown)
    $(this.$refs.submodal.$el).on("hidden.bs.modal", this.onShown)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <modal ref="modal"></modal>
  <button @click="$refs.modal.show()" class="btn">Show Modal</button>
</div>

<template id="submodal">
  <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input ref="input" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->

</template>

<template id="modal">
  <div>
    <div ref="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">

      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" style="height: 80vh">
            Stuff
            <input ref="input" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button @click="showSubModal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show Sub Modal</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
    <sub-modal ref="submodal"></sub-modal>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is still there.. as you can see here https://imgur.com/1D2CWwp, the scroll bar for #modal disappears after closing #submodal. you are then unable to scroll up to see the top of #modal

Comment: @Warrio check it now, it should work. In general, I think opening a modal from another modal is a bad idea, but this should get you there.

Comment: @Warrio There is some text added right before the example regarding `modal-open`.

Answer (score 4):

That work for me:

```
$('#my-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('body').addClass('modal-open');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding modal-open not solve "**focus out of modal by tab**" for me. After hours of researching only one thing that works for me is the most simple way:  hide 1-st modal before show 2nd, and show 2nd after hide 1st.

```js
$('#modal1').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#modal2').modal("hide");
})

$('#modal2').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#modal1').modal("show");
})
```