# Opening modal from other modal , Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I am opening modal from page, it opens totally fine, but when I try to open that same modal with same button from other modal (opened on same page), it refuses to be shown. What could possibly be problem?

EDIT: My, bad I forgot to post code.
It's awful design, but here is how modal dialog looks like:

```
        <div id="modalEditArticle" class="container modal fade" role="dialog" style="margin-top: 10%">

        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row vertical-offset-100">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">      
            <div class="alert alert-danger" id = "errorMessage" style="display: none"></div>  
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Edit article</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <form id="editArticleForm" method="PUT" action="/article/edit" class="form-horizontal col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1" role="form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Article name:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter article name" id="name" name="name" type="text" readonly="readonly">
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Unit price:</label>
                              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter unit price" id="unitPrice" name="unitPrice" type="text" >
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Description:</label>
                              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter description" id="description" name="description" type="text" >
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input id="id" name="id" type="text" style="display: none">
                          </div>

                          <!-- Select Basic -->
                          <label>Choose article type:</label>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <select id="articleType" name="articleType" class="form-control">
                                <option value="Drink" >Drink</option>
                                <option value="Food">Food</option>
                              </select>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Amount (in grams for Food, in milliliters for Drink):</label>
                              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter amount (in grams for Food,in milliliters for Drink)" id="amount" name="amount" type="text" >
                          </div>

                          <!-- Select Basic -->

                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Choose restaurant where it will be served:</label>
                              <select id="restaurantId" name="restaurantId" class="form-control restaurantId">
                              </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Update article">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </fieldset>
                  </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

And here is the button triggering it (just taken from other chunk of code):

```
 <button type="button" id="editArticleButton" class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditArticle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit </button>
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: is the nasted model button loaded throuth ajax

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528173/bootstrap-open-another-modal-in-modal

Comment: @RohitSharma Why should I add code, I tried before opening modal from other modal, and worked without additional Jquery code?

Comment: @ לבנימלכה My bad, here it is.

Comment: @KakulSarma nope, just html & bootstrap used.

Comment: what is your browser

Comment: @NigHamza I have tried this on latest stable versions of Chrome, Firefox and Edge, same behavior on all of them.

Comment: check ctrl+maj+i in chrome and see what console show you to understand the problem

Comment: @NigHamza Btw I tried already that, shows no errors (I know how to do basic stuff with inspect&debug in chrome).

Comment: how much modal you use if 2 is the second open and u want to open the first

Answer (score 0):

add both js files and use this http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/

```
   <div id="stack1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first" style="display: none;">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Stack One</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
        <p>One fine body…</p>
        <p>One fine body…</p>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" data-tabindex="1">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" data-tabindex="2">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" href="#stack2">Launch modal</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="stack2" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first" style="display: none;">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Stack Two</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
        <p>One fine body…</p>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" data-tabindex="1">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" data-tabindex="2">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" href="#stack3">Launch modal</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="stack3" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first" style="display: none;">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Stack Three</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" data-tabindex="1">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" data-tabindex="2">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Upvote for examples! But as I see it, it makes no difference whether I will open modal from page,  or from other modal (only href matters).

Comment: I recently edited my post and gave my html, you can see it now

Comment: i don't understand this sentence "I try to open that same modal with same button from other modal "

Comment: I have list of all articles on one page where each article has button which opens "Edit article" (modal dialog). Then on other page i also have list of restaurants, where each restaurant has some articles from above mentioned list of articles, and I can show them in modal dialog "Article list", and in that dialog each article (from that restaurant) has a button which opens same "Edit article" (modal dialog).