# Open boostrap modal on top of another modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have been trying to follow the tips in this topic [Bootstrap: Open Another Modal in Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528173/bootstrap-open-another-modal-in-modal) but I don't seem to be getting any results. I have two modals, the main one with id testModal and another one that opens when a link is clicked, with id salesModal.

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#salesModal', function (event) {
    //alert('Test Modal');
         var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
         $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
         setTimeout(function() {
             $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
         }, 0);
    });
```

but the salesModal still opens behind the testModal. Which part am I missing and doing wrong? As you can see, I had a debug alert in there to ensure that I am reacting at the right time, ie. when salesModal opens and that works fine.

Comment: Inspect your html with the developer console in chrome and check the z-index of each respective modal.   Make sure the 2nd interior modal has a higher z-index.

Comment: maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305821/multiple-modals-overlay

Comment: @ChrisHawkes that was it. The 2nd modal still had a lower z-index than the first one. Thank you :)

Comment: awesome, glad I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Layering Modals in Bootstrap can be strange but here is a quick bootply of how I normally do it. When the HTML is properly nested it should behave like below:
https://www.bootply.com/zg3CRlEMkV#

However when using the `data-dismiss="modal"` This will close all of the open modals. So you need to close the nested one via a JS call with an on click.

Answer (score 0):

## Open a Bootstrap 5.x modal over another modal over another modal and so on

*PREMISE: this works only if the opening of the modal is managed by Bootstrap adding and removing 'show' class*

I have found more smart to just reassign from bottom to top (at each and every event) the z-index automatically to all the modals whenever an event of Bootstrap modal showing or hiding is fired

I usually add this script at bottom of my HTML in my scripts section

```
const adjustModalZIndex = () => {
    const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal.show');
    const modalCount = modals.length;

    modals.forEach((modal, index) => {
        const baseZIndex = 1040;
        modal.style.zIndex = baseZIndex + (index * 20) + 10;
    });

    const backdrops = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-backdrop');
    backdrops.forEach((backdrop, index) => {
        const baseZIndex = 1040;
        backdrop.style.zIndex = baseZIndex + (index * 20);
    });
};

document.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', adjustModalZIndex);
document.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', adjustModalZIndex);
```